# Infromatica cloud- The Snowflake Connector failed to read data from the source because of the following error: null

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica-cloud

I am using custom SQL in  SQL override section in Advance property of snowflake source in IICS Informatica cloud.
`select (max(LAST_UPDATED_DATE)) from $$DB.test.org`. `$$DB` parameter is defined in the parameter file `$$DB=Dev`. Parameter is resolving correctly at run time but getting below error.

```
READER_1_2_1> SNOWFLAKECLOUDDATAWAREHOUSE_10000 [2020-10-30 03:07:00.440] [INFO] The Snowflake Connector uses the following SQL query to read data: select (max(LAST_UPDATED_DATE)) from Dev.test.org
READER_1_2_1> CMN_1761 [2020-10-30 03:07:00.440] Timestamp Event: [Fri Oct 30 03:07:00 2020]
READER_1_2_1> SNOWFLAKECLOUDDATAWAREHOUSE_10000 [2020-10-30 03:07:00.441] [ERROR] The Snowflake Connector failed to read data from the source because of the following error: [SnowFlake_READER__FAILED_906] The Snowflake Connector failed to read data from the source because of the following error: null
READER_1_2_1> CMN_1761 [2020-10-30 03:07:00.441] Timestamp Event: [Fri Oct 30 03:07:00 2020]
READER_1_2_1> SNOWFLAKECLOUDDATAWAREHOUSE_10000 [2020-10-30 03:07:00.441] [ERROR] Error occured while reading data using CCI Data Adapter  com.informatica.cci.runtime.internal.utils.impl.CExceptionImpl: Unable to get result data: Adapter read method has returned failure.
READER_1_2_1> CMN_1761 [2020-10-30 03:07:00.441] Timestamp Event: [Fri Oct 30 03:07:00 2020]
READER_1_2_1> CONNECTOR_10000 [2020-10-30 03:07:00.441] [ERROR] Error Occured while reading data from the source for Transformation - SRC_Organization | Connector Name - SnowflakeCloudDataWarehouse - Unable to get result data: Adapter read method has returned failure.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure the user that Informatica is using has permission to view the table `Dev.test.org`. Also, that seems like a strange table name, are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Yes user has permission on the table. An the table is also correct. Dev.test.org this is just for example.

Comment: If you create an identical job but that reads the table directly with no parameters and no SQL override then does it work? This will tell you whether it is a connection/permissions issue (copied job doesn't run) or an issue with the SQL Override/parameter (copied job does run)

Comment: A job with no parameter and no SQL override is running. It is the issue when I am using parameter.

Comment: Also, I just checked that, if I am removing parameter and passing full query in SQL override.. it still failing with same reason.. Seems like SQL override is not working in Snowflake connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the column list. Custom query should be like select (max(LAST_UPDATED_DATE)) as LAST_UPDATED_DATE from $$DB.test.org and the Field list should have only one column LAST_UPDATED_DATE. Mapping is working fine now.